# Exclude File Type From Rename Script

Tags: bash, file, rename

I need to exclude a single file type from the script below. Can someone show me what to add and exclusion for files that have a .partial extension?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /data/user1/upload
thetime=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S` #
for i in *.*
do
        extn=${i##*.} # save the extension of the file
                mv "$i" "${i%.*}"$(date "+_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.${extn}")
done
mv *.* /test/user1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you enable `shopt -s extglob` first, you can get all non-.partial files with `!(*.partial)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for all the files in the current path you can use find and search for files using a regular expression:

```
find . ! -name "*.partial"
```

This will give you all the files that don't match the "*.partial" regex.

Comment: Unfortunately I am a newbie to linux. Can you show me an example using the script I provided?

Comment: Instead of the 
`for i in *.*`
use 
`for i in $(find . ! -name "*.partial"); do echo "$i"; done`
But changing the echo command with whatever you want to do with the files.

Comment: After using this it does everything except for files that have spaces in the name. Example testfile.txt get renamed as desired but test file1.txt does not. How can I get the script also rename files with spaces?  find . ! -name "*.filepart" returns the file I want, excludes the ones that I want excluded, but treats files with spaces and seperate files rather than one filename.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the filtering within the loop with a guard clause that checks the extension of the file name, eg:

```
for i in *.*
do
    [[ "$i" =~ \.partial$ ]] && continue
    ...
done
```

When the value of `i` ends with `.partial` it goes to the next element.

In your particular case, since you already extracted the extension value, you can compare it directly `[[ "$extn" == "partial" ]]`

Comment: #!/bin/bash
cd /data/user1/upload
thetime=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S` #
shopt -s extglob
for i in *.!(partial)
> do
>         extn=${i##*.} # save the extension of the file
>                 mv "$i" "${i%.*}"$(date "+_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.${extn}")
> done
mv: cannot stat ‘*.!(partial)’: No such file or directory

Comment: @JT-66 I updated the answer using a different approach.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to make the above script completes the task againts multiple directories? Example /data/user1/, data/user2, /data/user3 ?

Comment: @JT-66 You can use a glob pattern for that, eg `data/*/*.*`.

Comment: I have tried several different variations and none seem to work. What am I missing?   thetime=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S` #
for i in *.*
do
    [[ "$i" =~ \.filepart$ ]] && continue
        extn=${i##*.} # save the extension of the file
                mv data/*/*.* "$i" "${i%.*}"$(date "+_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.${extn}")
done

Comment: You should use the glob pattern within the for construct, ie directly after `in` keyword.

Comment: I have tried for i in /data/*/*.* and it breaks the script. I apologize in advance due to the fact I am a unix newbie. It probably a syntax that I am not doing correctly.

Comment: @JT-66 If you still have this problem, I suggest you create a new question that includes the code that does not work.